# issue with performSegueWithIdentifier and rootViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, rootview

im using this line of code to perform a segue

`[self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewMessage" sender:self];`

but since i am calling `rootViewController` its attempting to look for the `viewMessage` idenifier in my `loginViewController` when i need it to be looking for it in `friendsListTableViewController` i tried just declaring `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewMessage" sender:self];` but i have two `@implementations` and `self` keeps recognizing as `JBSlidingTableViewCell1` and since its a UITableView its not recognizing the `performSeguqWithIdentifier` i tried `[friendsListTableViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewMessage" sender:self];` but all i get is that performSegueWithIdentifier isnt apart of that class when in fact it is a UIViewController...

Im trying to refrain from posting the code as much as possible since there is a lot too it but i just wanted to see if there is a way to FORCE `performSeguqWithIdentifier` to point to my `friendsListTableViewController` instead of my `loginViewController`

```
//
//  friendsListTableViewController.m
//  @ME
//
//  Created by Aaron Russell on 1/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Aaron Russell. All rights reserved.
//

#import "friendsListTableViewController.h"
#import "loginViewController.h"
#import "viewMessageViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "CCAlertView.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"


@implementation JBSlidingTableViewCell1

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@synthesize bottomDrawer1 = _bottomDrawer1;
@synthesize topDrawer1 = topDrawer1;
@synthesize titleLabel1 = _titleLabel1;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    if (nil != self) {
        self.titleLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 13, 304, 20)];
        self.titleLabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        self.titleLabel1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.titleLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.topDrawer1 addSubview:self.titleLabel1];
        _bottomDrawer1 = nil;

        // Top drawer

        self.topDrawer1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.topDrawer1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.topDrawer1];
    }

    return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    _bottomDrawer1 = nil;
    topDrawer1 = nil;
    _titleLabel1 = nil;
}


- (void)closeDrawer1 {
    if (self.topDrawer1.hidden == YES) {
        CATransition* animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.delegate = self;
        animation.type = kCATransitionFromRight;
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        animation.duration = 0.8f;
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [self.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        self.contentView.hidden = NO;
        self.bottomDrawer1.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)openDrawer1 {
    self.topDrawer1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.bottomDrawer1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

    [self bottomDrawerWillAppear1];
    [self insertSubview:self.bottomDrawer1 belowSubview:self.contentView];

    CATransition* animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    self.topDrawer1.hidden = YES;
    self.contentView.hidden = YES;
}


- (void)bottomDrawerDidDisappear1 {
    // Can be overridden by subclasses.
}

- (void)bottomDrawerWillAppear1 {
    UIButton *inviteToLocationBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose];
    inviteToLocationBtn.frame=CGRectMake(-40, -3, 150, 85);
    [inviteToLocationBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"invite.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [inviteToLocationBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callInvite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bottomDrawer1 addSubview:inviteToLocationBtn];

    UIButton *findBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose];
    findBtn.frame=CGRectMake(75, -3, 142, 85);
    [findBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"find.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [findBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callFind) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bottomDrawer1 addSubview:findBtn];

    UIButton *messageBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose];
    messageBtn.frame=CGRectMake(180, -3, 190, 85);
    [messageBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [messageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callChat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bottomDrawer1 addSubview:messageBtn];

}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        NSString *userurl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://mysite.com/invitegps.php?latitude=%@&longitude=%@&email=%@&friend=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude], [MyClass str], [MyClass temail]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:userurl];

        NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        if (theConnection) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:userurl delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Failure to Connect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}

- (void)callInvite {
    //TAKEN OUT FOR SIMPLICITY SAKE 
}


- (void)callFind {
    //TAKEN OUT FOR SIMPLICITY SAKE 
}

- (void)callChat {        
    [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewMessage" sender:self];
}

- (void)acceptLocationInvite {

}

- (void)declineLocationInvite {

}

- (void)acceptLocationRequest {

}

- (void)declineLocationRequest {

}

- (void)sendInstantMessage {

}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.topDrawer1.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [self bottomDrawerDidDisappear1];
    [self.bottomDrawer1 removeFromSuperview];
    self.bottomDrawer1 = nil;
}

@end

@interface friendsListTableViewController ();
@property (nonatomic, readonly) JBSlidingTableViewCell1* openedCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* openedCellIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray* regularCellStrings;

- (void)closeOpenedCell;
@end

@implementation friendsListTableViewController
@synthesize openedCellIndexPath = _openedCellIndexPath;
@synthesize regularCellStrings = _regularCellStrings;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize friends, friendList;

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"viewMessage"])
    {
        viewMessageViewController *dvController = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvController.email = [MyClass temail];
        [self presentViewController:dvController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (nil != self) {
        _openedCellIndexPath = nil;

        self.regularCellStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First default cell", @"Second default cell", nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    _openedCellIndexPath = nil;
    tableView = nil;
}


- (JBSlidingTableViewCell1*)openedCell {
    JBSlidingTableViewCell1* cell;

    if (nil == self.openedCellIndexPath) {
        cell = nil;
    } else {
        cell = (JBSlidingTableViewCell1*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.openedCellIndexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}
- (void)closeOpenedCell {
    [(JBSlidingTableViewCell1*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.openedCellIndexPath] closeDrawer1];
    self.openedCellIndexPath = nil;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    [self closeOpenedCell];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    friendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    NSString *someOtherString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://atmeapp.com/friendlist.php?userid=%@", [MyClass str]];

        NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someOtherString]];
    tbxml = [[TBXML alloc]initWithXMLData:xmlData];

    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    if (root)
    {
        TBXMLElement * allFriends = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"friend" parentElement:root];
        while (allFriends !=nil)
        {
            TBXMLElement * friendid = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"friendid" parentElement:allFriends];
            NSString *fid = [TBXML textForElement:friendid];
            TBXMLElement * fname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"fname" parentElement:allFriends];
            NSString *firstName = [TBXML textForElement:fname];
            TBXMLElement * lname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"lname" parentElement:allFriends];
            NSString *lastName = [TBXML textForElement:lname];
            NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@", firstName, lastName, fid];
            [friendList addObject:fullname];
            allFriends = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"friend" searchFromElement:allFriends];
        }

        //TBXMLElement *fname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"fname" parentElement:elem_PLANT];
    }

}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate + UITableViewDatasource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [friendList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[[JBSlidingTableViewCell1 alloc] init] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    friendsFullNames = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    NSArray *myWords = [[friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    friendsFullNames.text = myWords[0];
    NSLog(myWords[1]);
    UIImageView *bgImageFile = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UIImageView *imageFile = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    NSString *friendAvatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://www.atmeapp.com/images/users/", myWords[1], @".jpg"];
    [imageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
    [bgImageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
    //imageFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NUMBER_OF_ROWS - indexPath.row];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    [self closeOpenedCell];
    [(JBSlidingTableViewCell1*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] openDrawer1];
    NSArray *myWords = [[friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    [MyClass settemail:myWords[1]];
    NSLog(@"%@", myWords[1]);
    self.openedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
}
- (IBAction)inviteAFriend:(id)sender {
    NSString *userurl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://atmeapp.com/friendreq.php?userid=%@&friendid=%@", [MyClass str], eMailTextField.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:userurl];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:userurl delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Fail" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}

- (void)inviteFriend:(id)sender {
 }

- (void)declineFriendRequest {

}
/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate


- (IBAction)inviteFriends:(id)sender {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        // Email Subject
        NSString *emailTitle = @"You have been invited to @ME!";
        // Email Content
        NSString *messageBody = @"<h2> Try @Me </h2> <br /><br /> <p>Beta is finally ready! Please visit link below, Beta is NOT available in the App Store yet. <br /> <br /> <a href='http://www.atmeapp.com/download.php'> Get @ME Now! </a> <br /> <br /> Brought to you by <a href='http://www.teknologenie.com> TeknoloGenie </a> </p>";
        // To address
        NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"aaron@teknologenie.com"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
        [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Account Found" message:@"You need to add an email account to your device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        // optional - add more buttons:
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add Account"];
        [alert show];
    }

}


- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier should be called (on self) from within the view controller that's the source view controller of the segue.  You could call it from another controller, but you would need a reference to the source view controller to call it on. It's unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: i cant call self because i have more then one @implementation in the same class. I had to do so to have the effect of a sliderDrawer to open. Basically my UITableView contains a friends list, i swipe over a cell, and 3 buttons show up, one of those buttons is a message button which when i touch it calls `callChat` void, that is inside the `@implementation JBSlidingTableViewCell1` inside that `callChat` is where im attempting to perform the segue, im not really sure how to explain it further, if you would like i could post all the code...

Comment: I assume that the segue is hooked up directly to the view controller, friendsListTableViewController? You need to get a reference to that controller from within you implementation of JBSlidingTableViewCell1. I'm not sure how to do that since I don't know the structure of your app. Is thatJBSlidingTableViewCell1 part of an external framework you're using?

Comment: updated my question with code

Comment: its not apart of an external framework, i actually added the 1 at the end because im also using it again on my homeViewController where it displays notifications and has the same swipe effect but with 2 buttons a accept and decline.

Comment: basically im trying to start a converstaion between the two people, the person im clicking and myself, the view im getting to is viewMessageViewController in the end, see my `prepareForSegue`

Comment: What is the sequence of controller in your app? You say loginViewController is the root view controller of the window. Where does friendsListTableViewController come in the hierarchy, and how do you get to it from the login controller? Are there other controllers also?

Comment: so heres how it works, loginViewController once logged in goes to homeViewController, i click on a button that goes to friendsListTableViewController from there i click on a cell, click message and call the line `[messageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callChat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bottomDrawer1 addSubview:messageBtn];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29549/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-aaron-russell)

Comment: if you dont mind can we move this to a chat room to prevent unwanted extended comments? also theres a bunch of other views but there not relevent to this isue, for example i have a registerViewController that shows if a user clicks a button on the loginViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of your app, it seems like the only way to get a reference to the friendsListTableViewController is to look up the chain of views. Since, the method nextResponder will return the view controller of a view that it's responsible for, the following should get you a reference to the needed view controller from the custom cell's implementation file:

```
self.superview.superview.nextResponder
```

In this case, the superview of the cell is the table view, and that table view is in a subview of the controller's main view, so self.superview.superview gets you to the controller's self.view. The documentation for nextResponder says this: " UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one)". So, calling nextResponder on the controller's self.view, gives you the controller.

Comment: great explanation of what the nextResponder does, thanks a billion.